# How to add bootstrap grid with database result using php

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

I am newbie in php. i am using the following code to get my desired data from mysql database. but what i want to do, whenever database show a result i want to put it into a bootstrap grid( like col-sm-4) each time. Right now my  grid is coded in HTML, how can i generate it with the query result each time ? thanks in advance.

```
    <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <h3>image </h3><br>
                         <?php 
                        $sql = "SELECT * FROM sctable";
                        $result = mysql_query($sql);
                        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                        { 
                        $link = "http://localhost/sc/uploads/" .$row[1];
                         echo "<img width='100%' height='200' src=$link />"."<br />"; 
                         echo "";
                     }

                    ?>
                </div>
```

Comment: @RiggsFolly Not sure what either of those technolocies are needed for. OP just needs to wrap his image in `<div class="col-sm-4"></div>`

Comment: @Ohgodwhy You may be right after a third reading I think I see what he wants

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this where you just want to put each rows data into its own div

```
<?php 
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM sctable";
     $result = mysql_query($sql);
     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
     { 
         echo '<div class="col-sm-4">';
         echo '<h3>image </h3><br>';

         $link = "http://localhost/sc/uploads/" .$row[1];
         echo '<img style="width:100%;height:200px" src="' . $link . '"/>'; 
         echo '</div>';
     }
?>
```

Just for future reference, its a bad idea to use the full url for your own site in code like this. If you move it to a live site this code wont work anymore. Better to use relative paths and let the system do some of the work for you. So it should work whatever the domain is where you move the code.

```
<?php 
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM sctable";
     $result = mysql_query($sql);
     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
     { 
         echo '<div class="col-sm-4">';
         echo '<h3>image </h3><br>';
> Changed next line
         $link = "sc/uploads/" .$row[1];

         echo '<img style="width:100%;height:200px" src="' . $link . '"/>'; 
         echo '</div>';
     }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just wrap the image:

```
echo "<div class='col-sm-4'> <img width='100%' height='200' src='$link' /></div>";
```

Comment: ahh...this is so simple, i tried it earlier..must had make some mistake with the double quote and single quote. its working perfectly for me now. thanks for your help.